# Correct technique to find application in 32 and 64 bit versions of Vista/Windows 7 from CMD.EXE

Tags: windows, batch-file, 64-bit, windows-command-prompt

### BACKGROUND

I have an existing CMD script that works fine. It launches an app from PROGRAM FILES like so

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\MyApp\app.exe"
```

### PROBLEM

- it works fine on 32-bit versions of Windows (Vista, Windows 7)
- but on 64-bit versions of Windows the app will be installed into "Program Files (x86)" and not "Program Files" (which is what happens on the 32bit OS)

### WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR

- A script that robustly handles both cases (i.e. it "does the right thing" depending on the OS it is on)
- a method that uses only those features found in CMD.EXE. I *Am* curious about solutions that use Powershell, etc, but those don't help me - Powershell will not be on the machines this script will run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to [Matt's correct answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/9009/correct-technique-to-find-application-in-32-and-64-bit-versions-of-vista-windows/9028#9028). Basically in this version the complete path is verified.

```
SET AppExePath="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyApp\app.exe"
IF NOT EXIST %AppExePath% SET AppExePath="%ProgramFiles%\MyApp\app.exe"
%AppExePath%
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the best that I could come up with:

```
set strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles%
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" set strProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
"%strProgramFiles%\MyApp\app.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to test for for the ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable to determine if you're in 64bit Windows or not.  Here's a sample batch file.

```
if "%programfiles(x86)%zzz"=="zzz" goto 32BIT
echo 64-bit Windows installed
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\MyApp\app.exe"
goto END

:32BIT
echo 32-bit Windows installed
"%PROGRAMFILES%\MyApp\app.exe"

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to run the script under the 32-bit `cmd.exe`, so that it can take advantage of WOW64 filesystem redirection and [environment variable modifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274.aspx). If you can modify the caller, you don't even have to modify the script in question.

You could even have the script detect when it's executing under the 64-bit `cmd.exe` and restart itself using the 32-bit `cmd.exe`:

```
@echo off
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" goto :x86
echo Restarting using Wow64 filesystem redirection: %0 %*
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c %0 %*
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:x86
rem Rest of script follows...
```

Note that getting this hack wrong may result in spawning endless `cmd.exe` processes. That's why I used `goto` and a label instead of `if ... ( ... )`: command line parameters may contain parentheses, and `if ... ( ... )` performs a greedy search for the first closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do this in one (very) robust line:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\MyApp\app.exe" || "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyApp\app.exe"
```

The `||` executes the second command only, if the previous command failed (aka "not found").

Answer (score -2):

THE SCRIPT BELOW CAN DISPLAY THE OS TYPE OF A WINDOWS PC

```
@echo off
echo Checking OS Architecture....
echo Architecture identified!
echo.
set OSA=%processor_architecture%
IF %OSA%==AMD64 (
ECHO This is a 64-bit Operating System
) ELSE (  
echo This is a 32-bit Operating System
)    
echo.
Pause
```

Comment: This is incomplete and may fail on some (rare - but the question was for a "robust" solution) machines. Possible values for %processor_architecture% are `AMD64`, `IA64`, `ARM64`, `EM64T` and `X86` in which you script would fail in 3/5 cases.